# How to get dylibs in /opt/local/lib to be recognized by dlopen in MacOS Monterey?

Tags: macports, dylib

I am trying to compile some nim code that depends on libsass, and it fails with

> dlopen(libsass.dylib, 0x0002): tried: 'libsass.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libsass.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libsass.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/emre/code/nimforum/libsass.dylib' (no such file)
> could not load: libsass.dylib

On my system, that file is in /opt/local/lib, since I installed it with macports. I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH, to /opt/local/lib but this did not help. I believe macOS's System Integrity Protection module is the cause but I am not sure how best to accommodate it.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with SIP.

You need to pass the full path to the library you want to open to the first argument of dlopen().  From the man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
     #include <dlfcn.h>

     void*
     dlopen(const char* path, int mode);

DESCRIPTION
     dlopen() examines the mach-o file specified by path.
```

If you really need to use dlopen() to load this, you should be passing `dlopen("/opt/local/lib/libsass.dylib", RTLD_NOW)`.

However, `dlopen()` is generally frowned upon as it bypasses a lot of the performance and correctness benefits of static linkage.  You should aim to use static linkage (ie: pass `-lsass` at build time) wherever possible.